# Alternative to stringstream for speed

Tags: visual-studio, performance, c++11, boost, stringstream

I am using C++'s std::stringstream for aggregating logs(working on VC++ with C++11). I read they are inherently slow, so I am looking for a faster, if possible typesafe alternative. I am thinking of using sprintf otherwise instead. Is there some standard formatter in boost I can use maybe?

Comment: Don't just read, *try* it yourself. Time it, benchmark it, test it out. And remember that "good enough" usually *is* good enough. don't fix it if it isn't broken in the first place. :)

Comment: this should be on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: stringstream has the advantage that you can buffer multiple logging lines into the stream if you decide you can't safely spool to the log file "right now". The only real overheads vs sprintf is the occasional resizing of the internal buffer and perhaps getting the str() output. If you really feel the crunch after profiling, you can overload basic_stringbuf to use a more aggressive allocator and give direct access to the underlying string storage.

Comment: Try FastFormat or karma::generate, **after** profiling the app and making sure the issue is with formatting and not e.g. file buffering.

Comment: @GemTaylor What about overhead  due to being locale
aware?

Comment: @КоеКто The locale awareness adds very minimal formatting. The usual performance issue with streams is due to synchronization with the C apis. I've never heard that _stringstream_ was slow before.

Answer (score -2):

This [library](https://github.com/Isameru/stringbuilder) seems address your problem. Although I haven't tried it.

P.S. Boost has [The Boost Format library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/format/doc/format.html). But I don't know whether it faster. For better performance you should cache `boost::format` result.